# MouseEnter equivalent in android

Tags: android, .net, drag-and-drop

I want to port my windows phone game to android. I used the MouseEnter-event but didnt find anything in android.

The workflow is, you touch on area1 and "drag" it on a other area2. Drag means in this case, touch in area1, leave area1 "drag" it out to area2, area2 enter (finger press is inside) and release. I dont want to use a real drag and drop cause its not necessary and I thought for better performance.

Comment: u should implement this `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`  listener it will allow you to handle all gesture according to ur game i think it helps..

Comment: If it is not a "real drag", it is a touch event. Take a look at [Input Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html), especially the onTouch event.

Comment: there is no mouse enter. there is touch event down, drag, and up.